# I want to use gates and polices with Customer authentication

Tags: laravel

I am using this method for authentication

 `$customer = Customer::where('customerid', $customer->getId())->first();
        Auth::guard('customer')->login($customer);`

I check auth its return true

`Auth::guard('customer')->check();`

this method return false

`Auth::check();`

My problem is Gates and polices only works with **User** authentication I want to use gates and polices with **Customer** authentication

Comment: Well, all customers are users for sure, but not all users are customers. You may need to stablish a role and permissions system and auth users only, then use role to set permissions or redirects

Comment: Can you share your `Customer` model?

Comment: `namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class Customer extends Authenticatable
{`